# What studies are there showing the effectiveness of any substance on canine hypertension?

Tags: pharmacology, blood-pressure, dogs

Searching on http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov I could only find the article titled as "Telmisartan Treatment of Refractory Proteinuria in a Dog".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this consensus statement](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=17552466) (PMID 17552466):

J Vet Intern Med. 2007 May-Jun;21(3):542-58.
**Guidelines for the identification, evaluation, and management of systemic hypertension in dogs and cats.**
Brown S1, Atkins C, Bagley R, Carr A, Cowgill L, Davidson M, Egner B, Elliott J, Henik R, Labato M, Littman M, Polzin D, Ross L, Snyder P, Stepien R; American College of Veterinary Internal Medicine.

It includes 185 references, at least a dozen of which are related to your question. Also, if you look to the right of the article on PubMed, there are links to other relevant articles.

FYI: I located this article using search string

```
(canine hypertension) NOT pulmonary Filters: Review
```

There are quite a few others. (Canine pulmonary hypertension is apparently a popular research topic, so I found it useful to exclude those.)